# what is the difference between addFirst(element) and push(element) methods of Deques interface in java?

Tags: java, collections, deque

According to the link given below, addFirst(element) and push(element) methods of Deque interface of methods perform same function i.e. adding element to head. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these methods?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deque-interface-java-example/

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), which explains all the methods and what the differences between them are.

Answer (score 4):

JavaDoc for `push` says it all for you

> This method is equivalent to {@link #addFirst}.

Answer (score 1):

They do the same.

For compatibility reasons with legacy class `Stack` the `push/pop/peek` methods exist. This means they are there only to make transition of old code easier for the programmer.